# What does the numbers in apt-cache showpkg "packagename"output in Forward Dependencies section?

Tags: dependencies

I am new to Linux and I am trying to understand what are these numbers inside the bracket for eg: libattr1 (2 1:2.4.46-8) what this 2 1:2.4.46-8 stands for.
Thank you in advance your help will be highly appreciated.

Dependencies: 
libattr1 (2 1:2.4.46-8) libbz2-1.0 (0 (null)) libc6 (2 2.15) libgamin0 (16 (null)) libfam0 (0 (null)) libldap-2.4-2 (2 2.4.7) libpcre3 (0 (null)) libssl1.0.0 (2 1.0.0) zlib1g (2 1:1.1.4) init-system-helpers (2 1.18~) perl (0 (null)) lsb-base (18 3.2-14) systemd (2 29.1) mime-support (0 (null)) libterm-readline-perl-perl (0 (null)) spawn-fcgi (0 (null)) openssl (0 (null)) rrdtool (0 (null)) apache2-utils (0 (null)) ufw (0 (null)) lighttpd:i386 (32 (null))

Answer (score 0):

Apt uses deb packages. Deb packages can depend on other packages with specific versions.

The list is a set of dependence separated by spaces where each dependency follows the format `package_name (compare_integer version_range)` The compare_integer represents the type of comparison to make in the version specified by the package and the version the package manager can provide. It is nibbled with the lower 4 bits represent the comparison which are 1: =>, 2: <=, 3: >, 4: <, 5: ==, 6: !=, 0: null and the upper 4 bits are flags.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Are these numbers important while adding these dependencies in the chroot or they are only for the information? Also, can you provide the link where I can read the detail information about these numbers. @jdwolf

Comment: They are primarily information. The package manage then will decide which dependencies it needs to meet the requirements of the package you requested and also install packages that are dependencies.